# WPF&MVVM: Библиотека System.Windows.Interactivity больше не доступна?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

В рамках [урока](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.5.php) по паттерну `MVVM` для приложений `WPF` мне нужно было добавить библиотеку `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` через `Reference Manager`. Я её там не обнаружил (версия Visual Studio - 2017). На скриншоте ниже - всё, что есть в результатах поиска, начинающееся с `System.Windows`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я подумал, что возможно данная библиотека уже встроена в новую версию проекта WPF (хотя в списке уже подключённых ссылок её тоже нет), и когда добавил нижеследующий код в `ApplicationViewModel.cs`, никаких ошибок пока что не было отображено средой разработки:

```
private RelayCommand doubleCommand;
public RelayCommand DoubleCommand {
    get {
        return doubleCommand ??
        (doubleCommand = new RelayCommand(obj => {
            Phone phone = obj as Phone;
            if (phone != null) {
                Phone phoneCopy = new Phone {
                    Company = phone.Company,
                    Price = phone.Price,
                    Title = phone.Title
                };
                Phones.Insert(0, phoneCopy);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Однако, когда я добавил код XAML, то среда выдала сообщение о том, что в пространстве имён `clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity` не существует `Interaction`, `EventTrigger` и `InvokeCommandAction`:

```
<Window x:Class="MVVM_Tutorial.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVVM_Tutorial"
        xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<!-- ... -->

    <Button Content="2x">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                    Command="{Binding DoubleCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedPhone}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>

<!-- ... -->

</Window>
```

Не знаю, каким образом это связано с библиотекой `System.Windows.Interactivity`, но как следует решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Требуемая библиотека является частью `Microsoft Expression Blend 4 SDK` и не включена в стандартную поставку, но вы всегда можете подключить ее из `NuGet Gallery`: [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF by Microsoft](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF/)

Пользователи Visual Studio 2017 могут установить Microsoft Blend SDK в систему с помощью Visual Studio Installer, для этого на вкладке "Отдельные компоненты" ("Individual components") в разделе "Пакеты SDK, библиотеки и платформы" ("SDKs, libraries, and frameworks") необходимо установить галочку напротив пункта "Пакет SDK для Microsoft Blend для Visual Studio для платформы .NET" ("Blend for Visual Studio SDK for .NET") и нажать кнопку "Изменить".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого, библиотека System.Windows.Interactivity станет доступна из Reference Manager в разделе Assemblies/Extensions

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также, Blend SDK можно загрузить и установить в систему из центра загрузок Microsoft: [3.5](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22829), [4.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)