# Как в WPF textblock присвоить текст с ссылками,которые работают при нажатии?

Tags: c#, wpf, text

Так как  я делаю так  `<TextBlock   Text="{Binding Messages/Text}"/>`
,то ссылки отображаются `<https:// и т.д>` как сделать,чтобы они были такими:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример текста
"Hello!\r\n\r\n---\r\nЭто сообщение проверено на вирусы антивирусом Avast.\r\nhttps://www.avast.com/antivirus\r\n"

В результате должно быть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А какая строка у вас на входе?

Comment: @АндрейNOP  я получаю сообщение с почты используя imapclient.GetMessage(0).BodyText

Comment: Ну так покажите пример входной строки. Тaм HTML или что? Для отображения HTML есть WebBrowser

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил.

Comment: И как вы хотите чтобы этот текст был выведен?

Comment: @АндрейNOP добавил.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы ссылки стали кликабельными? Просто самый первый скрин - это что-то большее, там у ссылок еще и подписи

Comment: @АндрейNOP да..

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76378/discussion-between-nikita-and--nop).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы написал поведение для `TextBlock`, которое преобразует входную строку в набор `Inline`-блоков. Подключите библиотеку [System.Windows.Interactivity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/218063) и добавьте в проект такой класс:

```
class HighlightingHyperlinksTextBlockBehavior : Behavior<TextBlock>
{
    // Это свойство зависимости, в которое будем помещать входную строку
    public string Text
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
        set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string),
            typeof(HighlightingHyperlinksTextBlockBehavior), new PropertyMetadata("", TextPropertyChangedCallback));

    // Этот метод будет вызываться при изменении свойства Text
    static void TextPropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var behavior = (HighlightingHyperlinksTextBlockBehavior)d;
        if (behavior.AssociatedObject == null) return;

        // Отписываем все существующие "старые" Hyperlink от RequestNavigate
        foreach (var hlink in behavior.AssociatedObject.Inlines.OfType<Hyperlink>())
            hlink.RequestNavigate -= OnRequestNavigate;
        // Очищаем у связанного TextBox коллекцию Inline'ов
        behavior.AssociatedObject.Inlines.Clear();

        // Преобразуем символы \n\r в реальные переводы строк
        var text = Regex.Unescape((string)e.NewValue ?? "");
        // Шаблон для Url
        var pattern = @"(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?";
        // Ищем все Url во входной строке и собираем из них Hyperlink'и
        var hlinkParts =
            Regex.Matches(text, pattern)
                 .OfType<Match>()
                 .Select(m => m.Value)
                 .Select(s => new Hyperlink(new Run(s)) { NavigateUri = new Uri(s) })
                 .ToArray();
        // Остальные куски текста (которые не входят в Url) просто помещаем в Run'ы
        var runParts =
            Regex.Split(text, pattern, RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture)
                 .Select(s => new Run(s))
                 .ToArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < hlinkParts.Length + runParts.Length; ++i)
            // И добавляем в нее по очереди Run и Hyperlink
            behavior.AssociatedObject.Inlines.Add(i % 2 == 0 ? runParts[i / 2] : (Inline)hlinkParts[i / 2]);

        // Подписываем все "новые" Hyperlink на RequestNavigate
        foreach (var hlink in hlinkParts)
            hlink.RequestNavigate += OnRequestNavigate;
    }

    static void OnRequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Регулярное выражение для Url я взял [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041965/6766879)

Проверяем:

```
<TextBlock xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:HighlightingHyperlinksTextBlockBehavior Text="{Binding Text}"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Получается вот что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: +1, но разбор текста — не дело UI, этим должна бы по хорошему заниматься VM. (А ещё у `Hyperlink` есть свойство `NavigateUri`.)

Comment: @VladD: Ну если основной функцинал приложения не зависит от разобранной строки, то делать для этого отдельную VM, мне кажется избыточным, потом надо передавать коллекцию VM-объектов и собирать итоговую строку в ItemsControl... Если нам нужно просто вывести такой текст с кликабельными гиперссылками, удобно иметь для этого готовый контрол, в конце концов есть же готовые контролы типа WebBrowser или всякие AvalonEdit. Правда, для больших текстов придется делать разбор как-то асинхронно. Про NavigateUri забыл, обновлю ответ уже завтра теперь.

Comment: Разбор текста — это задача для модели. Ну то есть если всё просто, то особых проблем нет делать в UI, но с усложнением грамматики всё больше и больше появляется необходимость сделать отдельно разбор и отдельно UI.