# Преобразование ссылок

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Я передаю в RichTextBox значения string.

В этих string содержится как текст , так и ссылки.

Можно ли как то эти ссылки преобразовывать в гиперссылки (т.е. на которые можно нажать) и по ссылкам подгружать картинки ?

Картинки - имеется ввиду, что по этой ссылке хранится картинка (т.е. прямая ссылка на картинку в интернете), которую нужно отобразить в textBox.

Comment: Для таких вещей есть RichTextBox.

Comment: @LLENN пробую с RichTextBox, нужно изменить какие то свойства чтобы он преобразовывал ссылки ? Или же ему как то отдельно передавать ссылки и отдельно текст ?

Comment: Здесь было что-то подобное: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/817455/218063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В свойствах `RichTextBox` `DetectUrls` включите.
И событие `LinkClicked` выставить на функцию обработки клика по url, например:

```
Process p = new Process();

private void richTextBox1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
   p = Process.Start("IExplore.exe", e.LinkText);
}
```

Для WPF могут подойти следующие решения:

```
 <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True" />
```

или этот:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="Hyperlink_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
</RichTextBox>
```

Функция:

```
private void Hyperlink_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hyperlink = (Hyperlink)sender;
    Process.Start(hyperlink.NavigateUri.ToString());
}
```

Comment: DetectUrls вроде как нет в WPF у RichTextBox

Comment: Под рукой нет где попробовать, но смысл тот же, есть элемент, он стандартный, и свойство это у него есть. Вероятно обращаться к нему надо в xaml описании.

Comment: Дополнил про wpf