# Binding коллекции Run в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Есть TextBlock, в нем находится несколько элементов Run. Можно ли как-то динамически менять эти элементы через Binding?
Абстрактно это выглядит вот так

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1">
         Binding Runs       
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Менять что конкретно? Количество Run'ов?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, количество и параметры

Comment: Штатно нельзя, потому что `Inlines` не является свойством зависимости, да и только для чтения к тому же. Можно попробовать что-то замутить с поведениями, нечто отдаленно похожее я делал здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/817455/218063