# Привязка событий окна к команде WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

никак не могу найти способ привязать команду или метод из ViewModel к View, во время события Window_Closing. Мне нужно сохранять данные при закрытии, хотелось бы сделать это не используя code-behind. Пожалуйста помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подписка на подобные события делается при помощи `EventTrigger`.

- Добавляем в XAML пространство имен:

  ```
  xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
  ```
- Подписываемся:

  ```
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Closing">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnClosingCommand}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  ```
- Ну и тестовая команда пусть будет такой:

  ```
  public ICommand OnClosingCommand { get; }

  public MainViewModel()
  {
      OnClosingCommand = new RelayCommand(Close);
  }

  private void Close()
  {
      Debugger.Break();
  }
  ```

Все, после закрытия окна, будет вызван метод `Close`.

---

<sup>[Про System.Windows.Interactivity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/220553)</sup>

Comment: Подписываемся мы ведь в теге окна ?

Comment: @ЕгорЯсиновский Ну подумайте логически. "Событие закрытия окна", значит где  это должно все быть?

Comment: Спасибо, почему то дизайнер ругался на участок кода привязки, никак не мог понять почему, ситуация исправилась сама собой.

Comment: @ЕгорЯсиновский Все дизайнеры у студии довольно глючные и часто они не видят то, чего есть. Решается простой очисткой и затем сборкой проекта. Если ответ вам помог, то не забудьте его принять (галка слева).