# Обработка события LostFocus с использованием паттерна MVVM C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, события

В ходе разработки приложения столкнулся с такой проблемой - как обработать различные события у элемента. В качестве примера  решил взять событие LostFocus, чтобы понять принцип обработки элемента textbox. По ходу изучения увидел, что при обработки события нажатия кнопки используются ICommand, но к примеру у textbox нет свойства Command, и как это обработать неизвестно.

Comment: Для чего вам это событие? Обычно подобное событие используют для изменения цвета или других свойств View. Если так, то это все делается в XAML при помощи триггеров, в коде это будет являться нарушением MVVM. Если же у вас специфическая задача, то такие события отлавливаются примерно [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1097417/220553).

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь.