# Расфокусировка элементов WPF. Как убрать фокус?

Tags: wpf, focus

Имеется страничка WPF с различными элементами, такими как: TextBox, PasswordBox, ListView.

Если фокус был на TextBox, и я кликну на PasswordBox — фокус будет передан последнему, но я не смогу снять фокус вообще.

Вариант с прописанием Grid/Window или другому "контейнеру" функции KeyDown *не дал никаких результатов*.

---

**Как создать функцию, которая при клике вне области любого из элементов очистит фокус?**

---

Дополнено:

В стиле для TextBox и PasswordBox я прописал следующие триггеры:

```
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#f3ca40"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
```

Так вот, возможность редактировать текст внутри элемента пропадает, когда использую любой из методов @EvgeniyZ, фокус вроде бы снят, однако, почему-то не меняется цвет у Border'а на "Transparent".

Comment: Любопытно, а зачем такое вообще понадобилось?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ: Потому что иначе криво выглядит программа, когда фокус остаётся у элемента...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В WPF есть такая вещь, как `Keyboard.ClearFocus();`, она сбрасывает фокус с элементов при вызове.
Имея такой метод, мы можем его вызывает, например при клике мыши по самому окну, где клик будем отлавливать событием `MouseDown`, что в итоге даст нам такое:

```
<Window ... MouseDown="Window_MouseDown" >

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox/>
        <PasswordBox/>
    </StackPanel>
    
</Window>
```

и C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
    private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) => Keyboard.ClearFocus();
}
```

Выглядеть это будет так:
[image: Result]

Видим, что фокус успешно сбрасывается при клике за пределы элементов.

Мы можем пойти дальше и сделать на основе этого, к примеру свой класс поведения (`Behavior`):

1. Подключаем [System.Windows.Interactivity.WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/726434/220553) или лишь [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf/)
2. Создаем новый класс с нужным нам названием и пишем в нем примерно следующее:

   ```
   class ClearFocusBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
   {
       protected override void OnAttached()
           => AssociatedObject.MouseDown += AssociatedObject_MouseDown;

       private void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
           => Keyboard.ClearFocus();

       protected override void OnDetaching() 
           => AssociatedObject.MouseDown -= AssociatedObject_MouseDown;
   }
   ```
3. В XAML, к нужному объекту добавляем наше новое поведение, я, например перепишу код выше:

   ```
   <Window ...
           xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors">
       <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
           <local:ClearFocusBehavior/>
       </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

       <StackPanel>
           <TextBox/>
           <PasswordBox/>
       </StackPanel>

   </Window>
   ```

Результатом будет аналогичное поведение, что и выше.

---

Альтернативным путем решения может послужить метод `.Focus();` у нужного компонента, например на основном `Grid` (`<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">` и `mainGrid.Focus();`).

---

> а можно ли как-то логический фокус убрать?

За него отвечает `FocusManager`, при помощи которого мы можем задать фокус нужному объекту (`.SetFocusedElement()`), а если ему задать `объект, null`, то он должен этот фокус убрать. Как я понял, без разницы какой объект, я эксперементировал с тем же главным окном и все успешно сбросило. Так что, если вам именно такой вариант нужен, то:

- Вариант через событие и его `sender`:

  ```
  private void Window_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      if(sender is FrameworkElement element)
      {
          FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(element), null);
          Keyboard.ClearFocus();
      }
  }
  ```
- `Behavior`:

  ```
  private void AssociatedObject_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
      FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(AssociatedObject), null);
      Keyboard.ClearFocus();
  }
  ```

Если будут проблемы, то как я сказал выше, ищите выделенный объект, а не как здесь объект, к которому было добавлено поведение и который вызывает событие.

Comment: Я попробовал каждый из способов.. почему-то у меня ни один не работает..

Comment: @KoryJaxx Показывайте свои попытки, я не экстрасенс. У меня как видите, пустой проект, где лишь разметка что выше и код также из ответа и все работает (гифка тому доказательство).

Comment: Да, я понял, в чём была проблема. Фокус действительно пропадает, но есть одно "но". У элементов не вызывается ивент LostFocus(). Я попытаюсь решить это сам, спасибо)

Comment: Оптимальным вариантом оказалось задать Grid'у или StackPanel'и Name и в первом способе, при вызове ивента, отдавать фокус этому элементу. На мой взгляд, путь кривой.. но работает. Я уже гуглю дня 3, пока более красивого пути не нашёл.

Comment: @KoryJaxx Ну это как минимум нарушение MVVM подхода, что в WPF проекте не есть хорошо. А так, я вам уже сказал, без самодостаточного примера, где будет воспроизведена эта проблема я вам вряд-ли чем помогу, ибо все мои издевательства, код выше успешно прошел. Исследуйте свой проект, смотрите где вы что такого понаделали, что у вас не убирается фокус стандартными методами.

Comment: Дополню вопрос сейчас, с кодом в комментариях беда..

Comment: @KoryJaxx `Keyboard.ClearFocus();` - ключевое слово `Keyboard`, а значит `IsKeyboardFocused`.

Comment: Понял, а можно ли как-то логический фокус убрать?

Comment: @KoryJaxx, за логический отвечает `FocusManager`, попробуйте что-то по типу такого: `FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(FocusManager.GetFocusScope(element), null);`.

Comment: А что такое element и как его задать? Задал так: UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;

Comment: Большое спасибо, выбрал вариант с behavior, дополнил его для чистки логического фокуса и всё работает как часы!

Comment: @KoryJaxx Я дополнил если что ответ.